# Changing audio and grammar to make listener grock message

Tags: audio, accessibility, text

I am looking for a bridging application that takes voice input and outputs the same message using a given preselected accent and intonation, possibly even with grammar changes, which would make the message, more grockable, to the listener.

This assumes the listener can only understand text provided in a given format.

The AI must be smart enough to convey the same message in different words so that the listener understands.

And it can mine user phone calls and text messages to understand the format.

Anyone know anything that does anything like this, or that does something similar?

Thanks.

(I think, intelligence, regarding this flexibility, would allow both the speaker and the listener to understand, each other's, formats (and put them into practice ! :-) ).